# Error when trying to click a button using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am coding Add to cart functionality on WellGosh.com using Selenium on Python.

I have the code get the correct size to add to cart and log into my account and get to the right shipping address, but when I try to confirm the shipping method (fedex) it will not let me click on the continue button.

Here is an example of the code to checkout:

```
def Checkout():
#brings you to your cart
driver.get('https://wellgosh.com/checkout/cart')

#clicks to checkout
checkout=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="shopping-cart-table"]/tfoot/tr/td/div[2]/a')
checkout.click()

#Log in
login=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login-email"]')
login.send_keys(e_mail)
password=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login-password"]')
password.send_keys(Pass)
LogIn=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkout-step-login"]/div/div[2]/div/button')
LogIn.click()
cont=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="billing-buttons-container"]/button')
cont.click()
driver.implicitly_wait(100)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="shipping-method-buttons-container"]/button')
element.click()
```

I am getting this error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible

This is the snippet of the HTML code:

```
    </script>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons-set" id="shipping-method-buttons-container">
        <p class="back-link"><a href="#" onclick="checkout.back(); return false;"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left plain"></i>Back</a></p>
        <button type="button" class="button btn-continue" onclick="shippingMethod.save()">Continue</button>
        <span id="shipping-method-please-wait" class="please-wait zoooooom" style="display:none;">
            <i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin plain"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: So, if the id for the parent element of the continue button is "billing-buttons-container", where is this ID in your HTML snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code and let me know whether it solved your problem:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait(driver, 10).until(visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Continue"]'))).click()
```

Answer (score -2):

If you're having trouble clicking the button, why not run the javascript that is in the 'onclick' attribute of that button? For example, in your HTML snippet, instead of finding the element and clicking it, you could do:

driver.execute_script("shippingMethod.save()")

Note, if this page uses iFrames, you have to switch the driver to the appropriate iFrame, before you can find / select and of the child elements within it.

Comment: It's a very bad practice to directly invoke given page api methods instead of using user interface.

Comment: This is true, strange it gives an element not visible exception. This usually means something else might need to be clicked to make the element visible. Do any of the parent elements not in the snippet have a display of 'none'?